# How to pick a date in kivy 2.0.1

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am using kivy 2.0.1 with python 3.9, in my application I need to give the user the ability to choose a date to start something, but I can not find how to do this, for this two lines :

```
from kivy.uix.datepicker import DatePicker
```

and
form kivy.calendar import Calendar

I have the same error, module could not be found, in the API reference https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.html, I can not found anything about datepicker or calendar

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you saw that, but if it's not in the docs, then it's because it doesn't exist. What you are probably looking for is [`MDDatePicker`](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.1/components/datepicker/), which is provided by the [KivyMD library](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.1/). It offers some new widgets that you can use in your kivy apps. Of course, you could code your own DatePicker with plain Kivy, but that's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know a bout kivymd, but I found strange that kivy comes without datepicker (it's an important widget for all applications)